# Why does order of T-SQL where statements matter?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, optimization, ssms

Why, when opening a query like the following:

`WHERE     (statement1) AND ((statement2) OR (statement3))`

does SSMS query designer refactor it into the following syntax:

`WHERE     (statement1) AND (statement2) OR
                   (statement1) AND (statement3)`

I assume it has something to do with how SQL server parses the query, running ands before ors?

Is there a general rule of how to the best order of statements for ultimate optimisation?

Having run my own tests, the 2nd query knocks 0.5ms off the processing time. Its small, I know, but would increase with the complexity of the query (still makes almost no difference) and I have a general interest in how SQL server works.

Comment: How are you running your timing tests? Did you run the queries multiple times? Did you run query 1, immediately followed by query 2? If so, did you also try them in reverse order? I wouldn't have expected there to be any difference between them.

Comment: I ran even more tests and they seem less conclusive the more I run.

Comment: To measure SQL execution use [`SET STATISTICS IO ON`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184361.aspx) and [`SET STATISTICS TIME ON`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190287.aspx). Do not use the elapsed time, that is useless.

Comment: Once SQL Server has the data cached in memory subsequent queries may appear much faster.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the actual SQL execution. Unlike most languages you know, T-SQL [does not have boolean operator short circuit](http://rusanu.com/2009/09/13/on-sql-server-boolean-operator-short-circuit/)<sup>1</sup> and concepts like 'running ands before ors' make no sense, the order of evaluation is entirely driven by the query optimizer decisions and the may end up being completely different from what you write, or what you expect.

The expression rewrite you see seems to be entirely an artifact of the SSMS query designed internal parser.

<sub>1 Or better said the boolean short circuit cannot be determined imperatively by how you write the expression. Actual run time operator short circuit *does* happen, you just can't know *if* and *when* it will happen.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

In general, there is no guarantee for how SQL Server evaluates the Where clause. The optimizer will always try to find the most efficient way to execute the query.

To determine execution order, you should get an execution plan for your query (which you can get via SSMS). However, keep in mind this plan may change depending on what the optimizer thinks is the best query given current various statistics and resources.

Comment: The execution plans are identical, no matter the order of the where statements (I assume this is because SQL Server rearranges them to be the same behind the scenes).

Comment: @jaypeagi - So I guess you have your answer. The SQL Server query plan generator and optimizer are very smart pieces of software. And, how you construct your query often won't look like what the engine does after it rewrites it.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases you do not have to bother with understanding how SQL optimized a query to make it perform better. SQL knows things about your data which you don't :-)

Normally the best thing you can do is to give SQL the indexes it needs to retrieve the information in an optimal way. Then the query is optimized to execute in the best way.

Compare this to normal compilers which perform lots of changes to optimize the code. The best thing you can normally do is to write code which is maintainable and the compiler will take care of the rest. SQL is just the same, understand what you want to retrieve and SQL will retrieve it for you in the most optimal way.